# Distribute Events by Topic on Android

Tags: android, event-based-programming

I am new in the Android environment, and trying to publish topic events, currently using "[EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)" framework, but can not seem to find an option to do so.

Example:

Say I have a "ConversationUpdateEvent" but would like to fire the event by topic, or key for a specific conversation Id.

Something like:

**Subscribe:**

```
Conversation conversaiton = new Conversation(String conversationId)
```

**Fire:**

```
EventBus.post(conversaiton)
```

Only subscribers to the exact conversation Id will get notified

Comment: what is this EventBase ? can you give some details on it ?

Comment: I am sorry, I write it with a typo, I'ts :https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: i am not aware of EventBus, but you can find some good post  here http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/11/28/android-how-to-use-the-greenrobot-eventbus/

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I'ts the same library, no way of posting a topic based event..

Comment: I hope this will help @MCMatan https://stackoverflow.com/a/38186244/3983054

Comment: @KingofMasses Thanks again, the answer does is switch case, I'ts something i would like to avoid

Comment: Ok, Interesting. I am also looking for the answer to this question now :) Hope some one will help